# How to setState in different component React native?

Tags: javascript, react-native

My data from the api is loaded in a component and returns a view containing the values, which does show in the other component. But I want an activity indicator on that page to show until the data is completely loaded.

I've followed some tutorials about setState with parent-child, child-parent, sibling-sibling and parentless relations. But none seem to work the way I want it.

This is the screen that shows first. It starts with the 'refreshing' view, which will show an activityindicator until the state.refreshing is set to false.

```
export default class AgendaScreen extends React.Component {
    static navigationOptions = {
        title: "Agenda" 
    };
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state={
            refreshing: true
        }

    }

    render() {
        if (this.state.refreshing){
            return(
                //loading view while data is loading
                <ImageBackground source={ScreenBackground} style={styles.container}>
                    <View style={{flex:1, paddingTop:20}}>
                        <ActivityIndicator />
                    </View>
                </ImageBackground>
            )
        }  
        return(
            <ImageBackground source={ScreenBackground} style={styles.container}>
                <ScrollView>
                <ImageBackground style={[styles.header,{justifyContent:'flex-end'}]} source = {HeaderImage}>
                    <Text style={{color:'white', fontSize:12, alignSelf:'center', backgroundColor:'transparent', marginBottom:2}}>
                        Complete summary
                    </Text>
                </ImageBackground>
                    <Text style={styles.text}>Agenda</Text>
                    <Dates />
                </ScrollView>
            </ImageBackground>
        );

    }
}
```

This is the dates component, which gives me the view that I call with  in the previous code block.

```
export default class Dates extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        data:[],
        fill:[],
        refreshing:true,
        dates:[],
        list:[]
    }
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.getData();
}

getData() {
    fetch("API")
    .then((result)=>result.json())
    .then((res=>{
        this.setState({
            data:res,
            refreshing:false
        });
        this.setState({
            fill:this.state.data[0]
        });
        this.getDates();
        this.loop();

    }))
    .catch(error =>{
        console.error(error);
    });
};

onRefresh() {
    //Clear old data
    this.setState({
        data:[]
    });
    //Function to call api for latest data
    this.getData();
};

getDates() {
    var str = t(this.state.test, 'content.rendered').safeString
    var arr = str.split(',');
    var dates = [];
    arr.forEach(function(e) {
          dates.push(e.match(/;(\d{0,2}.[a-zA-Z]+)/g)[0].replace(';',''));
        });
    this.setState({
        dates: dates
    }) 
};
tempList=[];
loop(){
    for (x=0;x<this.state.data.length;x++)
    {
        var fill=this.state.data[x]
        this.tempList.push(
            <View style={{flex:1}}>
            <FlatList
                data={[fill]}
                renderItem={({item})=>
                    <View>
                        <Text style={styles.text}>
                        {t(item, 'title.rendered').safeObject}
                        </Text>
                    </View>
            }
            refreshControl={
                <RefreshControl 
                    //refresh control used for pull to refresh
                    refreshing={this.state.refreshing}
                    onRefresh={this.onRefresh.bind(this)}
                />
            }
            keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
        /></View>
        )
    }
    this.setState({
        list:this.tempList
    })
}

    render() {    
        return(
          <View style={{flex:1, borderWidth:10}}><Text></Text>{this.state.list}
          </View>
        );
    }
}
```

What I need is when Dates succesfully loaded his data from the api and returns the view, that the AgendaScreen state.refreshing will be stated to false.

Answer (score 0):

Add below to your AgendaScreen Component

```
this.refresHandler = (e) =>{

    this.setState({   
     refreshing:e
})
}
```

Add below props inside `<Dates />`

```
<Dates refresHandler={this.refresHandler}/>
```

change below code in Dates Component

```
getData() {
    fetch("API")
    .then((result)=>result.json())
    .then((res=>{
        this.setState({
            data:res,
            refreshing:false
        });
        this.setState({
            fill:this.state.data[0]
        });
        this.getDates();
        this.loop();

    }))
  .then(() =>{
      this.props.refresHandler(this.state.refreshing)
   })
    .catch(error =>{
        console.error(error);
    });
}
```

Comment: The activityindicator will keep running thus it will not show the data. When I put the `<Dates refresHandler={this.refreshHandler}/>` within the first view (which shows the activityindicator), I get this error. ```_this2.props.refresHandler is not a function. (In '_this2.props.refresHandler(_this2.state.refreshing)', '_this2.props.refresHandler' is undefined)```

Comment: oh sorry there is typo in code ```this.refresHandler```  should come instead of ```this.refreshHandler```

Comment: I didn't know I had to put the function from the AgendaScreen just after(inside) the render, I thought it had to be outside the render. Now it works, but there is still a small delay between when the view is loaded and when the data is loaded. The data will show like 1 sec after the view is already loaded.